# convert legacy web application into WAR file

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, web-applications

We are migrating our servers and I need to deploy our legacy distributed web application into another server. But we don't have .WAR/.EAR files.

Is there any way I can create .WAR/.EAR files using some utilities as web application has other dependent applications like email creation, delivery web services, xml services and etc.

So I was thinking if .WAR/.EAR file creation is a good idea? if YES then is there any way I can do it easily?

If I can't create .WAR/.EAR file then how to migrate the whole application into another server without errors? Thanks.

Comment: ... why don't you have WAR/EAR files ?

Comment: When I joined the company the application was like that, without WAR/EAR as it is a legacy application created 15years before I suppose.

Comment: As of now, what gets deployed inside the tomcat ? any folders like structures  ? if not war/ear ?

Comment: yes, folders like structures - /opt/data/t1/vendorzone/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using development software such as RAD or Eclipse you can export your project as a .WAR/.EAR

That usually works for me.

As long as you have access to the original code

Comment: It is not that kind of project I can add in Eclipse as there are lots of dependencies and 10-12 types of environment setup files in linux.  I don't know about RAD. Thanks